# Cannot remove `xt_recent` module

Tags: iptables, kernel-modules, modprobe

Even after removing iptable rules that reference Recent module, I cannot remove the kernel module `xt_recent` and get the error that it is `still in use`.

```
user@host:~$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
user@host:~$ lsmod | grep xt_recent
xt_recent              24576  2
x_tables               40960  7 ip6table_filter,xt_conntrack,iptable_filter,xt_tcpudp,xt_recent,ip6_tables,ip_tables
user@host:~$ sudo modprobe -r xt_recent
modprobe: FATAL: Module xt_recent is in use.
``
```

Comment: Your `lsmod` output shows that `xt_recent` is in use by `x_tables`.

Comment: Once I loaded the `xt_recent` module, it is being loaded on boot. Is it a consistent behaviour? Do I need to run `modprobe xt_recent` on boot everytime if I want to use in iptables?